# Does similar reduced row echelon form implies same eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I understand, reduced row echelon form preserves a matrix row basis. Can I conclude if 2 matrices of same size have same reduced row echelon form, then they share the same eigenvectors?

Comment: No. The identity $2\times 2$ matrix has the same reduced row echelon form as the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$. But every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of the identity, and only the vectors of the form $(x,0)$ with $x\neq 0)$ are eigenvectors of the second matrix (my matrices operate on the left). Note that the range of matrix has to do with its *columns*, not its rows. (Also, elementary row operations preserve the *rowspace*, not the “row basis”).

Comment: The RREF of any invertible matrix is the identity matrix, so no.